# Since installing XP SP2 I can no longer access my IIS hosted web pages

Tags: iis

I had a base Windows XP with IIS hosting some websites and it has been working for years, yesturday I upgraded to SP2 (which includes the security suit) because I needed .NET 3.5 and since then no one can access the web pages anymore.

When I connect to the macine locally and try to access the webpage it prompted me for a username / password - when I entered it I was able to access the page locally.

However, remotely I always get "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"...
Anyone know what I need to do so that we can access the pages again?

Thanks,

Comment: Looks like it is the WINDOWS FIREWALL, when disabled it works again ... So I need to add something special to my windows firewall settings?

Answer (score 0):

You need to open port 80 on the firewall.  Alternatively, if you box is behind a hardware firewall, just turn off the windows firewall.

Answer (score 0):

add an exception to the windows firewall settings for that IIS Application (port number if other)